# python - remove whitespace between two characters using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I have a pair of columns, like so:

```
x = ["a b williams", "e g", "z z specialists"]
y = ["j j winston", "hb d party supplies", "t t ice cream"]
df = pd.DataFrame(x,y)
```

I would like to be able to remove the white space between two single characters using `re.sub`. I have tried the following:

```
re.sub("(?<=\\w\\b)"\\s"(?=\\w\\b)", "", df)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I'm unsure of what I am doing wrong.  The desired result is:

```
jj winston             ab williams
hb d party supplies              eg
tt ice cream           zz specialists
```

Please advise.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `"(?<=\\w\\b)"\\s"(?=\\w\\b)"` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Is that `df` example representative? Do you really want to replace in the index? The regex is rather simple, you may use `r'(?<=\b[^\W\d_])\s(?=[^\W\d_]\b)'`. Or, if you really want to treat digits and underscores as word, `r'(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am unsure what you mean about index

Comment: I mean, `df.replace(regex_here,'', regex=True)` will not replace in the index column. Ok, does `re.sub(r'(?<=\b[^\W\d_])\s(?=[^\W\d_]\b)','', text)` work for you? Note you cannot pass `df` as input argument to `re.sub`, it must be a string. That is why I am asking about the real-life structure of your data.

Comment: I didn't intend for first column to serve as index, still getting up to speed on python.

Comment: Can you process the data before creating a `df`? Can you apply `re.sub` to the `x` and `y`?

Comment: what I'm trying to do involves an already created dataframe, hence me creating one out of x and y

Comment: So, does `df.replace(r'(?<=\b[^\W\d_])\s(?=[^\W\d_]\b)','', regex=True)` work for you?

Comment: No, only the second column is processed

Comment: Because you are running it against your current demo code, where the first column is an index column.

Comment: If the examples are representative, with the single characters being at the beginning of each string, couldn't this just be `re.sub('^(.) ', r'\1', df)`? Or do the actual data contain other cases where this wouldn't work?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You can't pass a dataframe to `re.sub` as input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I was just parroting the code in the question for that part; I don't know anything about pandas. I meant the regular expression itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<=\b[^\W\d_])\s(?=[^\W\d_]\b)
(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POvXV1/1). Note the `[^\W\d_]` pattern matches any Unicode letter in Python `re`. `\w` matches Unicode letters, digits, `_` and some diacritics and other connector punctuation.

*Details*

- `(?<=\b[^\W\d_])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a single letter as a whole word (as it is prepended with a word boundary)
- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `(?=[^\W\d_]\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a single letter as a whole word (as it is followed with a word boundary).

Here is a Pandas demo:

```py
x = ["a b williams", "e g", "z z specialists"]
y = ["j j winston", "h d party supplies", "t t ice cream"]
df = pd.DataFrame(x,y)
rx = r'(?<=\b[^\W\d_])\s(?=[^\W\d_]\b)'
df.index = df.index.to_series().replace(rx, '', regex=True)
df = df.replace(rx, '', regex=True)
# => df
#                                 0
# jj winston            ab williams
# hd party supplies              eg
# tt ice cream       zz specialists
```

As `DataFrame.replace` with `regex=True` does not touch the index column, it must be handled separately, hence the `df.index = df.index.to_series().replace(rx, '', regex=True)` line of code is added.

Comment: can you explain how the single digit pattern `\d_` works in this?  Is that simply saying there is one space?

Comment: @jvalenti `\d_` in the `[^\W\d_]` negated character class means `digit` and `_`, and the overall meaning is *any char but a non-word char, digit and `_`*. In other words, any word character but a digit and `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is pretty close to the required and can be slightly modified as follows:

```
r'(?<=\b\w)(\s)(?=\w\b)'
```

Note to use the raw quote r'...' so that you don't need double \ for in the regex.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7lcaz/1)

Better compile the regex to speed up the processing as it is used multiple times

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\b\w)(\s)(?=\w\b)')
```

Then reuse your codes:

```
x = ["a b williams", "e g", "z z specialists"]
y = ["j j winston", "h d party supplies", "t t ice cream"]
df = pd.DataFrame(x,y)
```

Convert the index:

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().str.replace(pattern, '')
```

Convert the data column:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(pattern, '')
```

Explanation of your errors:

1. You cannot use re.sub directly on the whole pandas DataFrame
2. Your regex contains 4 quotation marks "  where the 2nd " ends the regex and so the subsequent portion of regex is treated as continuation line by the \ mark and the characters after it was considered invalid after continuation line

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`, I suggest the following:

```
# your lists    
x = ["a b williams", "e g", "z z specialists"]
y = ["j j winston", "hb d party supplies", "t t ice cream"]

# replacements
x = [re.sub(r'(\b\w)(\s)(\w\b)', r'\1\3', el) for el in x]
y = [re.sub(r'(\b\w)(\s)(\w\b)', r'\1\3', el) for el in y]

# pd dataframe after the process
df = pd.DataFrame(x,y)
```